# C - printf unsigned int

Tags: c

I would like print an unsigned int like: `0x000000` because I have:

```
# define OFFSET    (u32) 0x21FE014
typedef unsigned int u32;
```

When I use printf like this:

```
printf("Offset: %zu\n", OFFSET);
```

It returned me: `35643412`

Comment: Don't use homebrew fixed width types! Use `stdint.h` and `limits.h`. The latter contains macros for the stdlib format strings. `int` is not guaranteed to have 32 bits.

Comment: And if you use types such as `uint32_t` from `<stdint.h>`, you should use `PRIX32` from `<inttypes.h>` to specify upper-case hex (in full, `printf("Offset: 0x%.8" PRIX32 "\n", OFFSET)`).  Although `#` prints `0x` or `0X` before the hex output, the case of `x` is the same as the case of the hex digits.  It looks as though you prefer lower-case `x` and upper-case hex digits (I do too), so the standard formats don't work according to your/my requirements.

Answer (score 1):

`%x` is `printf` format for hexadecimal output:

```
printf("Offset: %x\n", OFFSET);
```

Answer (score 1):

`%zu` means *print the corresponding **`size_t`** argument as an unsigned integer in base 10.*

What you want is `%x` to print an unsigned integer in hexadecimal without prefix; if you really want the `0x` prefix, use `%#x`.